# Apply a jQuery script already present in the page only the html called by Ajax, not on all html documents

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I created generalists jQuery scripts for all of my html tags:

`<script src="./Scripts/Public/Scripts.js"></script>`

I would like the html tags called by Ajax also benefit from these scripts. So I added the function $.getScript() in my code:

```js
$('.ajax-global').on('click', function(){
    var param = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.ajax-window').load('./Ajax/' + param + '.php', function(){
        $.getScript("./Scripts/Public/Scripts.js");
    });
});
```

The problem is that the code affects the entire page, or I wish it is limited to Ajax code called...

How to proceed?

Comment: Are you really calling `$('.ajax-window').load('./Ajax/' + param + '.php');` twice? BTW, looks like dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048551/getscript-local-load-instead-of-global

Comment: This is exactly what I would get: the original javascript code may be assigned to html called Ajax (to avoid rewriting the double only for Ajax) without pass again to all the document.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean. A concrete sample would be great, because now, it sounds like a XY problem: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Comment: BTW, if your issue is regarding events beeing bound twice, then delegate events instead, if possible...

Comment: Ok, here is an [example online](http://scriptura.github.io/#index-ajax), click on the "Welcome Stackoverflow" button.

Comment: There's no way to change what part of the DOM the script touches. If you want the script to only affect certain parts of the DOM, you should make it check variables that you set before loading it. Better yet, it shouldn't affect anything by itself, it should just define functions. After loading it, you can call the functions on the elements you want to affect.

Comment: I had actually forgotten to remove the code I called twice. I just correct in the original post. But, apparently, it has no impact on the problem.